# Error in Google Cloud Platform: The API "assistant" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assist-api

I am developing with google home with API.AI/Dialogflow. When I deploy to Actions on Google, the following error appears:

> Agent is not yet registered. Please visit
>   https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/assistant/overview?project=xxxxxxx

But when I visit the address, I receive the following message:

> The API "assistant" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to
>   access it

I have already activated the API assistant in google cloud.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/actions.googleapis.com/overview?project=**yourproject** and enable google actions api [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD5jv.png)

Then you will see the menu to configure your action in Directory listing.